# WS319 HUAWEI can not change IP address

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, ip

I have bought a HUAWEI WS319. It's default IP address is 192.168.3.1 and subnet 255.255.255.0

I want to change the IP of the router to 192.168.1.1
Reason being is I want this router to be the DHCP IP address supplier.
(All the pc's on my network already have static ip with gateway pointing to 192.168.1.1 too many to go around and change them all)

BUT ... If I change the IP I get an error message **LAN HOST IP ADDRESS IS NOT VALID**

The router will be located after my ISP router that has an IP of 192.168.1.50

DHCP is turned off on the ISP router.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD1y8.jpg)

Any help greatly appreciated.

BTW - if your wondering why I am doing this - its because this router has parental control to block URL such as facebook whereas the one from the ISP does not.

Thanks in advance
Shane

Comment: Firstly, your router likely has (at least) 2 IP addresses, in different subnets. I'm presuming you want to change the IP address on the WAN side, not the LAN side.

Comment: As i mentioned the new router will come after the isp router that has a static ip (192.168.1.50) and that new one will assign the ip addresses - so not sure what you mean by 2 ip addresses